# How do I connect Python to Shiny Apps without using R?

Tags: python, syntax-error, py-shiny

I have a python code and I want to make a shiny app out of it. The reason for this is because the packages that I'm using in python do not support each other when I'm doing it in R (keras and tensorflow).

```
rsconnect add \
      --account _____ \
      --name ______ \
      --token ______ \
      --secret <SECRET>
```

I tried the above code (provided by Shiny Apps) in python, but it's giving an invalid syntax error after the rsconnect part. How do I fix this? I searched online and it said that Shiny Apps is mainly used for R, but can I also use it for python? If not, what other web apps similar to Shiny can I used to deploy my app?

Comment: Shiny is, honestly, my nemesis. Just use [`reticulate`](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/) where needed to call into python. Otherwise, look at proper web frameworks like `dash` at a minimum

Answer (score 0):

You need to run that from the command line, not in a python script. See https://python-bloggers.com/2022/10/creating-deploying-shiny-apps-in-python/

Comment: Thanks! do you know how to open terminal in google colab? There isn't an option under "tools" anymore